# Count relationed items

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
* 

FROM Product.Stock AS PS 
INNER JOIN Product.Product AS P ON PS.ProductId = P.ProductId
INNER JOIN Product.ProductDetail AS PD ON P.ProductId = PD.ProductId
INNER JOIN Product.ProductSize AS PSI ON P.ProductId = PSI.ProductId
```

I want to know how many ProductsId with same SizeId I have, for example:

[image]

in this case I have two products with same ProductId and SizeId, so I wish get: 2 because I have 2 products with sizeId 1

ProductId comes from table: Product.Product
SizeId comes from table: Product.ProductSize

How can I achieve it? Regards

Comment: What do you want the result to be if there are multiple values for SizeId?  Do you want a table of SizeId and the number of products having that SizeId?

Comment: Count(productid) and Group by productid ?

Comment: I suspect not all those table are necessary for the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
PSI.SizeId, COUNT(DISTINCT P.ProductId)

FROM Product.Stock AS PS 
INNER JOIN Product.Product AS P ON PS.ProductId = P.ProductId
INNER JOIN Product.ProductDetail AS PD ON P.ProductId = PD.ProductId
INNER JOIN Product.ProductSize AS PSI ON P.ProductId = PSI.ProductId
GROUP BY PSI.SizeId
```

I'm assuming that the SizeId column is in the Product.ProductSize table.

Comment: I don't think you should be joining to the product detail table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Maybe not, but I assumed this was a simplified version of the real query, which may have predicates on ProductDetail.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Having Count` in order to just show sizes with multiple products and no need for inner joins, since you already have all the fields in one table:

```
SELECT  SizeId, COUNT(Distinct ProductId) 
    FROM  Product.ProductSize 
    GROUP BY SizeId
    Having Count(Distinct ProductId)> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Jack's answer, still I think joins seem to be redundant here.

```
SELECT
SizeId, COUNT(DISTINCT ProductId)

FROM Product.ProductSize 
GROUP BY SizeId
```